# Owl Carousel Slider Smoothly Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I created **Owl Carousel** Slider with auto play but it not sliding smoothly. Anyone know how to create following code run smoothly?

**Javascript Code**

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 1000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
  dots: true,
  items: 2,
  margin: 10,
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pfL9ws6c/)**

Comment: do you want to reduce the speed of carousel?

Comment: Look for another solution which uses CSS-transitions instead of Javascript animation

Comment: @techhunter I want smooth animation. Currently it not move smoothly you can see in jsfiddle demo

Comment: Looks pretty damn smooth on my end

Comment: @Sadikhasan have check actual demo [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html) and how smooth it is?

Comment: @GovindSamrow I want continue movement without waiting

Comment: @Sadikhasan Owl Carousel working with items not pixels or width so you to use another plugin or create some own :)

Comment: @GovindSamrow Thanks for guide me.I will use other.

Answer (score 1):

Hy there use following code 
must insert this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-slideshow").owlCarousel({

  // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    loop: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 5000,
    autoPlayTimeout: 5000,
    autoPlayHoverPause: true


  });

});
```

```html
<div id="owl-slideshow" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

 <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/images/wall1.png); height: 170px  !important;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/images/wall2.png); height: 170px !important;"></div>
 <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/images/wall3.png); height: 170px !important;"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

increase autoplay duration.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
  dots: true,
  items: 2,
  margin: 10,
});
```

Comment: I want slider like http://demo.st-marron.info/roulette/sample/demo.html which work smoothly